# x64dbg Windows APIs Stack details

Tags: reverse-engineering

as I'm diving into the reverse engineering topic, I was wondering: is there any way (if possible) to have the same level of details, regarding Windows APIs Stack setup and arguments (highlighted in the Immunity image) within x64dbg?

[immunity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETwue.png)

[x32dbg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hImI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try xAnalyzer, you can download it here: https://github.com/ThunderCls/xAnalyzer

Example output after applying this plugin:
[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ThunderCls/xAnalyzer/master/images/after_analysis.png]